# Getting undefined value in reactJS when substracting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the interval of time when the user started typing until he submitted his text. When he clicks on the text area the timer starts and gets calculated in seconds (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds). Same for the timer to end when he clicks submit.

Now my problem is that when I try to subtract the two values saved in `this.state`, even if I store them in a var first or if I do a `this.setState()`, I still get 'undefined'.

```
    overallTime(e){
        this.setState({Time: this.state.StartTime - this.state.EndTime})
        console.log(this.state.Time)
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        this.overallTime();
        var textinput = this.state.inputValue;
        var inputLength = textinput.length;
        var inputTime = this.state.Time;
        if(textinput === this.state.Content)
        {
            console.log(inputLength)
            var lps = inputLength / inputTime;
            this.setState({LettersPerSecond: lps})
            console.log(lps)
            this.setState({message: 'Your score is ' + this.state.LettersPerSecond + ' letters per second! Good job! Refresh the page for another try!'})
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({message: 'Your input is incorrect, refresh the page and start again! Remember, you always learn from your failures, so never give up!'})
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `setState` inside `setState` that doesn't seem right

Comment: I tried doing that after I saw another post on SO, but didn't work. Forgot to change it back, now I edited the post. Thank you

Comment: Have you bind `overallTime` to the component?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to call it as ```this.overallTime``` instead of ```this.overallTime()``` ?

Comment: Could you share the rest of code or a codesandbox?

Comment: I hope this is the correct link
https://codesandbox.io/s/small-pine-ymonf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest restructuring like this:

```js
overallTime() {
  return this.state.EndTime - this.state.StartTime;
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
  const totalTime = this.overallTime();

  const textinput = this.state.inputValue;
  const inputLength = textinput.length;
  
  if (textinput === this.state.Content) {
    const lps = inputLength / totalTime;

    this.setState({
      LettersPerSecond: lps,
      message: 'Your score is ' + lps + ' letters per second! Good job! Refresh the page for another try!'
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      message: 'Your input is incorrect, refresh the page and start again! Remember, you always learn from your failures, so never give up!'
    })
  }
}
```

#### Why?

```js
setState({Time: someValue});
// this.state.Time doesn't have the new value yet at this point
```

See – [State updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

There's also a minor logical error – you need to do `endTime - startTime`, not `startTime - endTime`.

Your `overallTime` function is not exactly right – I think you meant something like this:

```js
overallTime() {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    Time: state.EndTime - state.StartTime
  });
}
```

I strongly recommend reading through the [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) section of React docs – it's very well written.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorials. Yes, end time is set. There is a codesandbox link in the comments on the op. I am now using the code you provided, but I still am getting a NaN value for ```lps```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-payne-8c136?file=/src/App.js
This is the updated code, where I used your snippet.

Comment: You're seeing `NaN` because there was a typo in my `overallTime` function – it said `startTime` instead of `StartTime`. Also, after seeing your codesandbox, my snippet doesn't 100% fit in your code, you'll need to make some adjustments to make it all work. But it's close! You can do it!

Comment: Yes! Now it works with ```StartTime```! Still returns a value 1.06e-10, but it's going somewhere! Thank you!

Comment: You're getting that weird number because initially I assumed you're calculating time using [UNIX timestamps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now). (I'd recommend doing that – perhaps the most common way to do it, and simpler than calculating from hours, minutes, seconds). I edited the snippet to reflect your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use call back function of setState function. you will always get updated state in call back function.

for example:

```
overallTime(e){
    this.setState({Time: this.state.StartTime - this.state.EndTime}, 
     () => console.log(this.state.Time))  
}
```